# how to prevent cpu usage from changing timing in labview?

Tags: labview

I'm trying to write a code in which every 1 ms a number plused one , should be replaced the old number . (something  like a chronometer !  )  .

the problem is whenever the cpu usage increases because of some other programs running on the pc,  this 1 milliseconds  is also increased and timing in my program changes !

is there any way to prevent cpu load changes affecting timing in my program ?

Comment: How are you currently implementing this - can you post a screenshot or (preferably) VI Snippet of your code? You can access a millisecond timer value in LabVIEW, but as other answers have noted you can't depend on a computer running a desktop OS to do something reliably every millisecond (possibly unless you start writing code that runs at the OS's driver level, which is one of the things you can't do with LabVIEW).

Comment: the main problem is what I commented on "Dave_St" answer . I mean creating a sin wave without frequency oscillation using Daqnavi drivers and advantech PCi1710 card . it seems both problems have the same origin. I can send a code example if necessary.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DAQNavi, or that card, but what you need to do is use buffered output, where you send the card a waveform or array of samples and it outputs them at regular intervals according to its own hardware clock. If the driver and hardware can't do that then it's not a LabVIEW problem, it's a limitation of the driver and hardware. You need to read up on DAQNavi to find out if it's possible.

Comment: DAQNavi  usage is nearly just like DAQmx . Input buffer is working great but as you said I think output buffer and clocking is not supported on this card . unfortunately DAQNavi documentation is not so good at creating analog output . I can generate output signal without buffer but timing is a big problem now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as though you are trying to generate an analogue output waveform with a digital-to-analogue converter card using **software timing**, where your software is responsible for determining what value should be output at any given time and updating the output accordingly.

This is OK for stationary or low-speed signals but you are trying to do it at 1 ms intervals, in other words to output 1000 samples per second or 1 ks/s. You cannot do this reliably on a desktop operating system - there are too many other processes going on which can use CPU time and block your program from running for many milliseconds (or even seconds, e.g. for network access).

Here are a few ways you could solve this:

- Use **buffered, hardware-clocked** output if your analogue output device supports it. Instead of writing one sample at a time, you send the device a waveform or array of samples and it outputs them at regular intervals using a timing signal generated in hardware. Unfortunately, low-end DAQ devices often don't support hardware-clocked output.
- Instead of expecting the loop that writes your samples to the AO to run every millisecond, read LabVIEW's **Tick Count (ms)** value in the loop and use that as an index to your array of samples: rather than trying to output every sample, your code will now say 'what time is it now, and therefore what should the output be?' That won't give you a perfect signal out but at least now it should keep the correct frequency rather than be 'slowed down' - instead you will see glitches imposed on the signal whenever the loop can't keep up. This is easy to test and maybe it will be adequate for your needs.
- Use a **real-time operating system** instead of a desktop OS. In the case of LabVIEW this would mean using the Real-Time software module and either a National Instruments hardware device that supports RT, such as the CompactRIO series, or installing the RT OS on a dedicated PC if the hardware is compatible. This is not a cheap option, obviously (unless it's strictly for [personal, home use](https://www.labviewmakerhub.com/doku.php?id=learn:tutorials:libraries:linx:3-0)). In any case you would need to have an RT-compatible driver for your output device.
- Use **your computer's sound output** as the output device. LabVIEW has functions for buffered sound output and you should be able to get reliable results. You'll need to upsample your signal to one of the sound output's available sample rates, probably 44.1 ks/s. The drawbacks are that the output level is limited in range and is not calibrated, and will probably be AC-coupled so you can't output a DC or very low-frequency signal. However if the level is OK for what you want to connect it to, or you can add suitable signal conditioning, this could be a neat solution. If you need the output level to be calibrated you could simultaneously measure it with your DAQ card and scale the sound waveform you're outputting to keep it correct.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "not on a desktop computer." This is why products like LabVIEW Real-Time and dedicated deterministic hardware exist: you need a computer built around dedication to a particular process in order to consistently serve that process. Every application in a regular Windows/Mac/Linux desktop system has the problem you are seeing of potentially being interrupted by other system processes, particularly in its UI layer.

Comment: you said " every application in a regular windows ... " , Do you mean that there are some version of windows os which can operate in realtime ?  what is a realtime system ? is it os dependent or hardware dependent ?

Comment: A realtime system is not so much "realtime" as that it can guarantee a certain time tick interval upon which lines of code can be executed. Realtime systems guarantee in this way that code can be executed on a specified time tick and will behave deterministic with regards to execution time. Several realtime systems exist, amongst others windows embedded. Besides a realtime operating system I think you also need realtime hardware since at processor level there are also some difference.

Comment: @hesi DJ’s comments are accurate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent cpu load changes from affecting timing in your program unless the computer has a realtime clock.

If it doesn't have a realtime clock, there is no reason to expect it to behave deterministically. Do you need for your program to run at that pace?

Comment: Okay. The answer is no, unless he is using a computer with a realtime clock.

Comment: 2 months ago I tried to make a chronometer but the result was an imprecise one,  because of the problem I mentioned  . and now Im trying to create a sin wave using daqnavi and pci1710 card and this time frequency of the out put signal changes . so yes I really need to prevent lagging .

Comment: Most PC's have a real-time clock, but that's not why a user-level program on a PC can't do something reliably every millisecond.

Comment: @nekomatic - A fair point. I should clarify that I meant a computer classified as a realtime system, not just the presence of a realtime clock.